# Do the benefits of Oil of Sharpness stack with those of +X magic ammunition?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, stacking

Do the benefits of [*oil of sharpness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/oil-of-sharpness) stack with those of +1/2/3 magic ammunition?

I'm really just curious whether these also stack as +X ammo does with a +3 bow, or if there's a point at which things stop stacking.

Answer (score 18):

## Yes, all 3 bonuses stack

According to the official rulings in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=18) - *page 18*:

> In general, bonuses stack, unless they’re from the same spell

Also, in the DMG - *page 252*:

> When two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them — the most potent one — apply while the durations of the effects overlap. [...]  Game features include spells,
> class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic
> items.

These are items but they do not have the same name so this rule does not apply.

There is no specific rule on the [oil of sharpness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/oil-of-sharpness) or [Weapon +3](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weapon-3) or [Ammunition +3](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ammunition-3) that would override this, so the bonuses do stack.

Comment: The exact wording is "the coated item is magical and has a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls" - but isn't +3 ammunition already magical and already has a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls? Addressing this would greatly increase the reliability of this answer. Imagine a spell that says "For 1 hour, the target has 2 arms" and claiming that if cast on a normal person it would give them a total of 4 arms. That doesn't seem quite right to me!

Comment: @gszavae Merriam-Webster defines "bonus" as "something in addition to what is expected". Using your example, if a spell says "the target has 2 bonus arms", it would be equivalent to saying "the target has 2 additional arms". So yes, on a two armed person we would certainly expect the spell to result in four arms.

Answer (score 6):

#### The bonuses do not stack.

[Oil of Sharpness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/oil-of-sharpness) states:

> the coated item is magical and has a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls.

If I coat a piece of ammunition in the oil, it **has** a +3 bonus. The oil does not **add** a +3 bonus.

If I coat ammunition +3 in the oil, then claim the ammunition *has a +6 bonus*, my claim contradicts the rules for Oil of Sharpness, which state my ammunition **has** a +3 bonus.

Here's how it would play out if I was DMing:

> Player: I coat my +3 arrow in oil of sharpness, now it has a +6 bonus.
>
> DM: Let me check that, what does oil of sharpness say?
>
> Player: "the coated item is magical and has a +3 bonus"
>
> DM: Then we'll go with what it says, it "has a +3 bonus".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109683/discussion-between-nautarch-and-thomas-markov).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, bonuses from different sources stack. There can be more than one bonus for something - there are plenty of such examples in the game.

There can be a +3 bonus from one source and +3 bonus from a different source. Being from different sources, those bonuses stack.

As an additional argument, consider that Oil of Sharpness and a +3 weapons are both Very Rare items. The former is a single-use item, lasts only for 1 hour, and requires a minute to apply. This makes that +3 weapons much, much better. For that reason as well I would assume they were intended to stack.