# What options exist to remove (not just cancel out) disadvantage on ranged attacks at short range?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, advantage-and-disadvantage

Spelljammer is out, and with it, the long awaited rerelease of my favorite hippo-homies, the Giff! The Giff racial abilities give them *most* of the advantages of the Gunner feat, as well as some great options for grappling and such, that make them pretty well suited for a gun-wielding Monk (or Gunk) build.

Gun monk builds are a lot of fun, but one essential piece of the toolkit is the ability, gained from the Gunner or Crossbow Expert feat, to negate the disadvantage penalty for making a ranged weapon attack while in melee range. The Giff get all of the rest of the features of the Gunner feat for free - which makes burning a feat as Giff just to get this feature very unattractive.

What other ways are there to get this feature - whether from other feats or multiclass dips or magic items - that don’t require burning a coveted feat slot on a redundant feat?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for features that ignore the "disadvantage at close range" rule, or are features that simply offset disadvantage by giving advantage valid as well?

Comment: The former. Plenty of ways to get advantage and simply negate disadvantage exist, but that means it’s not possible to actually gain advantage, which is still pretty crippling to a build.

Comment: By short range, do you mean when an enemy is within 5ft?

Comment: @SeriousBri yes

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188512/increasing-chances-of-successful-ranged-attacks-for-a-blind-ranger-with-blind-fi

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you believe one deserves it :)

Answer (score 9):

### While it's from [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf), the Close Quarters Shooter Fighting Style does this.

> **Close Quarters Shooter**
>
> You are trained in making ranged attacks at close quarters. When making a ranged attack while you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature , you do not have disadvantage on the attack roll . Your ranged attacks ignore half cover and three‑quarters cover against targets within 30 feet of you. Finally, you have a +1 bonus to attack rolls on ranged attacks.

You may need to multiclass dip to get a fighting style. If you do, it's worth taking it first for extra proficiencies and proficiency in Constitution saving throws.

### Be invisible. Yep, it's yet another way in which being invisible is awesome.

You asked for any magic items that can help you attack without imposing disadvantage. There are a few magic items that grant invisibility such as a [Ring of Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4723-ring-of-invisibility) and a [Cloak of Invisibility](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/wondrous-items:cloak-of-invisibility) but these are powerful (expensive) magic items. There's also, of course, [Potions of Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4710-potion-of-invisibility) which are probably much easier to come by.

> Aiming a ranged attack is more difficult when a foe is next to you. When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a spell, or some other means, you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature **who can see you** and who isn’t incapacitated.

If you use regular *Invisibility*, it'll end as soon as you make your attack, so you'll only get the lack of disadvantage on that single attack. *Greater Invisibility* allows you to overcome this and keep attacking without disadvantage, or whatever else you want to do while invisible.

There are other ways to be unseen, such as obscuring your line of sight with thick foliage, and magical darkness. Some of these can easily be abstracted with hiding depending on the exact circumstances.

### As you mentioned, the Gunner and Crossbow Expert feats do this.

Both of these feats grant this, among other things:

> When making a ranged attack while you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature, you do not have disadvantage on the attack roll.

Credits: Much of my answer comes from [Miniman's answer](https://Are%20there%20any%20abilities%20for%20a%20Spellcaster%20to%20attack%20with%20ranged%20spells%20in%20melee%20distance,%20without%20imposing%20disadvantage?) for the question "Are there any abilities for a Spellcaster to attack with ranged spells in melee distance, without imposing disadvantage?" but I don't believe it is an exact duplicate question.

Comment: I was going to editorialize the "Yep, it's yet another way in which being invisible is awesome" but I fully agree with that wording!

Comment: I playtested the CQS fighting style pretty extensively, using it on a ranged focused Swords Bard for a campaign that ran about 8 months. *It is significantly stronger than any other fighting style available*. I really struggle to overstate how powerful it is as a fighting style, to the point that I am comfortable saying that it is as good as a mid-tier feat. It has a feature from Crossbow Expert, a feature from Sharpshooter, and an attack/damage bonus. It is wayyyy too good. Splitting it into two different fighting styles and removing the bonuses would make it balanced.

Comment: Given how good it is, it would make the Fighting Initiate feat actually worth it.

Comment: @NautArch: can you expand on that? From the quoted text, it seems that being invisible would remove disadvantage (by making the target not able to see the attacker) in addition to any other effects (eg., granting advantage). It's not that the advantage from invisibility cancels out disadvantage, it's that disadvantage doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @NautArch: I think that question's coming from the other direction. There, the invisible creature is the enemy; here, the invisible creature is "me" - if I'm the invisible creature, the (presumably visible) foe next to me can't see me, thus their presence doesn't impose disadvantage on me (even if I might impose disadvantage on them, which some of the answers there imply is the case).

Comment: @minnmass I stand corrected - thank you! I totally never noticed that rule had the same caveat as Opportunity Attacks about being seen. Kinda netting at a 0 because of the recommendation of UA without any commentary on it's use. This is a case where that subjective support would be really helpful for those looking to apply this answer in a game. A sort of caveat emptor for everyone :)